# read data NGXS Angular

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

i Am Making Authentication Using **`NGXS`**..
I am Trying to get Current User Data after Login and put it in the state to read it in homepage such as (username , email and userType)

my state function is working and set the new values in the state but i cant read it from home page after login

maybe the way that i am using to get current user data wrong

so i need to read the username and email that stored in GetCurrentUser State

> My `auth.state.ts` file

```js
export class AuthStateModel {
  token: string;
  email: string;
  user_name: string;
}
@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: "auth",
  defaults: {
    token: null,
    email: null,
    user_name: null,
  },
})
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static currentUser(state: AuthStateModel) {
    return {
      email: state.email,
      user_name: state.user_name,
    };
  }
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  @Action(GetCurrentUser)
  getcurrentUser(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>) {
    return this.authService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
      tap((x: any) => {
        const state = ctx.getState();
        ctx.patchState({
          email: x.email,
          user_name: x.user_name,
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

> NGX-logger-plugin from inspect element

```
next state {auth: {…}}auth: {token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJod…hYSJ9.nwYZyOmIVLLGx_1FvmrQ-u--6fp0nVphwRfNyE14Xsc", email: "asd@asd.com", user_name: "hsss"}
```

My `CompanyhomeComponent.ts` file

```js
@Component({
  selector: "kt-companyhome",
  templateUrl: "./companyhome.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./companyhome.component.scss"],
})
export class CompanyhomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetCurrentUser());
  }
}
```

Now how can i read it in CompanyhomeComponent.html i tried a lot of ways but nothing working

Comment: Could you tried to set and get session key

Comment: @AdamNorman how can i do it ?

Comment: away from session check this example and authService 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-get-token?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @AdamNorman thanks but their is a problem in the tutorial (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-get-token-pmlb2e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that is in appComponent Line 12 gives me under auth red line and says  ` Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AuthState'.
`

Comment: @Mr.Rakol The `state` parameter in your selector function is `any` type, because it's the entire application state, composed of the state model types of all the states imported into your root NgxsModule. `state.auth` is of type `AuthStateModel`.

Comment: its still not working and doesn't get the getCurrentUser Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component needs to select the value from the store. Since you have a `@Selector` defined, you can use that:

```
@Select(AuthState.currentUser) user$: Observable<any>;
```

or you can use `store.select` with the selector:

```
user$: Observable<any> = this.store.select(AuthState.currentUser);
```

or without:

```
user$: Observable<any> = this.store.select((state) => {
  return {
    email: state.email,
    user_name: state.user_name,
});
```

Then in your template you can use the async pipe:

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">
  <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
  <span>{{ user.user_name }}</span>
</div>
```

Side note: since you're returning an object with email and user_name, but not token, to avoid using `any`, you'd have to either declare it as an anonymous type:

```
Observable<{email:string; user_name: string}>
```

or use Partial:

```
Observable<Partial<AuthStateModel>>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps adding **@Injectable()** to the **AuthState** Class

Comment: thank you..i will add it...what will happen when i adding it??..and how can i read this data in my html component